# Expression Call with Type Combining lambda linq where

Tags: c#, linq, reflection, lambda, expression

I am trying to create a dynamic lookup filter for a `DataTable`.

The code look currently like this, I am looping through each Row/Column. (one table feed the other one)

```
    DataRow FoundRow=null;
             foreach (string ID in IDToCheck)
        {
                        FoundRow = IdTable.AsEnumerable().Where(row => row.Field<string>(ID).Equals(
                            RowInfo[ID].ToString(),StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)).First();
DoStuffWith(FoundRow);
        }
```

I do not manage to convert the `row.Field<string>(ID)` to `Expression.Call`.

I am trying to reproduce the example of [Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt654267.aspx).

Comment: Why would you want to do that? what's wrong with what you have? although it could be simplified to `IdTable.AsEnumerable().Where(row => IDToCheck.Contains(row.Field<string>(ID)))`

Comment: Actually it was not clear in question but `IDToCheck` is actually a `Column name idtocheck`. Both table have several column name in common. I am trying to match them together, if first ID is not found in table, then look for second ID and another column of the other table. (it is for sedol, isin...)

Comment: Ok, but i still can't see what's wrong with your current code?

Comment: I was thinking it would be faster with a compact lambda expression OR. I was thinking it would be faster to go row by row rather than column by column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if you will really get any performance gain by that.

But, just to answer the direct question: "to convert the row.Field(ID) to Expression.Call"

```
IQueryable<DataRow> queryableData = IdTable.AsEnumerable().AsQueryable();

// Get the generice "Field<string>(string)" method from DataRowExtensions
ParameterExpression pe = Expression.Parameter(typeof(DataRow), "row");
MethodInfo fieldMethod = typeof (DataRowExtensions).GetMethod("Field", new [] {typeof(DataRow),typeof(string)});
MethodInfo genericFieldMethod = fieldMethod.MakeGenericMethod(typeof (string));

Expression left = Expression.Call(null, genericFieldMethod, pe, Expression.Constant( col_name ));
Expression right = Expression.Constant(value);
Expression exp = Expression.Equal(left, right);

IQueryable<DataRow> results = queryableData.Where(Expression.Lambda<Func<DataRow, bool>>(exp, pe));
```